# Cordova alternative to UNIX cat command

Tags: file, cordova, concatenation, cat

Is there an alternative to writing my own Cordova cat plugin to concatenate files in Cordova?

My other (until now unsuccessful) approach can be seen here: [Merging multiple parts of a file in Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386354/merging-multiple-parts-of-a-file-in-cordova)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way, see my other question + answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386354/merging-multiple-parts-of-a-file-in-cordova).

In short you have to use the File API of cordova and the File API of HTML5 to read the fileparts and then put them together again with the FileWriter of Cordova. Be sure to use readAsArrayBuffer instead of readAsBinaryString!